# Which type of hamster besides syrians are the least bitey?

Tags: pet-selection, biting, hamsters, breeds

I want to get some sort of small hamster (winter white, campbell's dwarf, robo, etc.) but I would like to know which kind is the least likely to be all nippy and such. I am not exactly sure which to get since they are said to be a little less nice compared to Syrian hamsters.

Comment: First off, the answer to your question is that it's all about how they're raised. I would suggest re-wording it to ask more of how to tell at the store which ones have been handled better, so that you can handle them sooner once you take them home.